# How to call useContext in a function using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have defined context like below for setting states and is like below,

```
interface DialogsCtxState {
    isDialogOpen: boolean;
    setIsDialogOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
    itemVisible: boolean;
    setItemVisible: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const initialState: DialogsCtxState = {
    isDialogOpen: false,
    setIsDialogOpen: () => {},
    itemVisible: false,
    setItemVisible: () => {},
};

export const DialogsContext = React.createContext<
    DialogsCtxState
>(initialState);

export const DialogsContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(
        false
    );
    const [itemsVisible, setItemsVisible] = React.useState<boolean>(
        false
    );

    return (
        <DialogsContext.Provider
            value={{
                isDialogOpen,
                setIsDialogOpen,
                itemVisible,
                setItemVisible,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </DialogsContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

And i use this context in two components Uploadbutton and userbutton like below,

```
function UploadButton() {
    const {isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen, itemVisible, setItemVisible} = 
    React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const onUpload = () => {
        itemVisible && setItemVisible(false);
        setIsDialogOpen(isDialogOpen => !isDialogOpen);
    }
    return (
        <Button onClick={onUpload}/>
    );
}

function UserButton() {
    const {isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen, itemVisible, setItemVisible} = 
    React.useContext(DialogContext);
    const onAdd = () => {
        isDialogOpen && setIsDialogOpen(false);
        setItemVisible(prev => !prev);
    }
    return (
        <Button onClick={onAdd}/>
    );
}
```

the above snippet works fine. but i want to move the code withing onUpload and onAdd methods to DialogContext file which evaluates to something like below,

```
const onAdd = () => {
    function1(); //where thiscontains the code in onAdd before snippet.
}

const onUpload = () => {
    function2();//where this contains code in onUpload snippet before
}
```

what i have tried,

in file that contains DialogContext i tried something like below,

```
export const function1 = () => {
    const {isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen, itemVisible, setItemVisible} = 
    React.useContext(DialogContext); //error here
    isDialogOpen && setIsDialogOpen(false);
    setItemVisible(prev => !prev);
}

export const function2 = () => {
    const {isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen, itemVisible, setItemVisible} = 
    React.useContext(DialogContext); //error here
    itemVisible && setItemVisible(false);
    setIsDialogOpen(isDialogOpen => !isDialogOpen);
}
```

But i get the error react.usecontext is used in a function which is neither a react function component or custom react hook.

how can i fix this. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only use of the values returned from the context is to create the `onUpload` and `onAdd` functions. It will be a better approach to create the functions in the `DialogsContextProvider` component to pass them as value. Example

```js
// context
interface DialogsCtxState {
   onUpload: () => void;
   onAdd: () => void;
};

const initialState: DialogsCtxState = {
   onUpload: () => {},
   onAdd: () => {}
};

export const DialogsContext = React.createContext<
    DialogsCtxState
>(initialState);
```

The `DialogsContextProvider` component

```js
// context provider
export const DialogsContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(
        false
    );

    const [itemsVisible, setItemsVisible] = React.useState<boolean>(
        false
    );

    // onUpload function
    const onUpload = useCallback(() => {
        itemsVisible && setItemsVisible(false);
        setIsDialogOpen((isDialogOpen) => !isDialogOpen);
    }, [itemsVisible]);

    // onAdd function
    const onAdd = useCallback(() => {
        isDialogOpen && setIsDialogOpen(false);
        setItemsVisible((prev) => !prev);
    }, [isDialogOpen]);

    return (
        <DialogsContext.Provider value={{ onAdd, onUpload}}>
            {children}
        </DialogsContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

This is how it can be used in the `UploadButton` and `UserButton` components,

```js
const UserButton: React.FC = () => {
   const { onAdd } = React.useContext(DialogsContext)
  
   // rest of the logic
}

const UploadButton: React.FC = () => {
   const { onUpload } = React.useContext(DialogsContext)
  
   // rest of the logic
}
```

**Note** There are multiple typos in your code so if we ignore that the error occurred when you took the custom function approach because `useContext` can only be used in **functional components** and **custom hooks**. To solve the issue you have to take a custom hook approach. For example

```js
export const useOnUpload = () => {
  const { isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen, itemsVisible, setItemsVisible,
  } = React.useContext(DialogsContext);

  const onUpload = useCallback(() => {
    itemsVisible && setItemsVisible(false);
    setIsDialogOpen((isDialogOpen) => !isDialogOpen);
  }, [itemsVisible, setIsDialogOpen, setItemsVisible]);

  return onUpload;
};

// usage
function UploadButton() {
   const onUpload = useOnUpload();

   // rest of the logic
}

// similarly you can create the onUseAdd hook
```